# Can a PSU break a Graphic Card?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

My PSU stop working and dont restart, I think it was by overheat. This not the problem because I'm upgrading it this week.

The problem is that I connected a GTX 760 which requires 500W, to the 500W PSU, and just stop, maybe the problem was the current requeriments? Don't know.

My concern is: Could my PSU break my graphic card in this conditions? I mean by saturation or overheat...

I'm a bit noob on this terms.

Thank you.

Comment: your psu could break your card...if it does not give enough power it can damage the card and at the same time if it does some funky power actions like random spikes or brown outs then it can damage it also....You should always get a little bit more than what is required... in your case a 600w would not be a horrible idea.

Comment: It would be very unusual for a PSU to "overheat" the only way that would happen is if the PSU's fan itself failed.  If your GPU requires a 500W PSU then logic dictates you should install something that provides more than 500W.  You still have to power the CPU and HDDs but its very unlikely the PSU damaged your GPU that wouldn't happen if your PSU overheated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just looking for some comfort.  The answer to your question is 'maybe'.  You wouldn't know unless you test it with your new PSU.

I have a PSU failed on me once while the computer is on, and my graphic card still work after I installed the new PSU.  I hope that makes you feel better.

Anyway, there's a lot of PSU Calculator on the web where it will give you an estimate of number of watts you need for a PSU based on a given PC specification.

One example would be the [MSI PSU Calculator](http://us.msi.com/power-supply-calculator/)